# Div breaking flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ionic2

I have a `html` page and it has a list of buttons and above these buttons should texts be displayed. The problem is that when I add anything above this list, the layout breaks. I think I'm doing something wrong with `flex`.

That is how the page looks without any content above the list. **It looks good!**

[image]

That is the `css` for this page:

```
.topics-component {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    ion-content {
        scroll-content {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;

            ion-list {
                width: 300px;
                align-self: flex-end;

                button {
                    height: 55px;
                    margin-top: 10px;

                    ion-label {
                        color: color($colors, slate);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here its `HTML`:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>

</ion-navbar>

<ion-searchbar placeholder="Search..." hideCancelButton="true"></ion-searchbar>

<ion-content padding>
    <!--<div *ngIf="description">
        <span>{{title}}</span>
        <span>{{description}}</span>
    </div>-->
    <ion-list no-lines>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="let topic of topics" (click)="selectTopic(topic)">
            {{topic.title}}
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Now when I add some text above the list, the how layout breaks.

Here is the `HTML`:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div *ngIf="description">
        <span>{{title}}</span>
        <span>{{description}}</span>
    </div>
    <ion-list no-lines>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="let topic of topics" (click)="selectTopic(topic)">
            {{topic.title}}
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And here is the broken layout:

[image]

What am I missing?

**Update:**

So after adding `flex-flow: column` I got the following result:

[image]

The list is not on the bottom anymore.

Comment: It has to do with flex-flow that should be column for ion-content

Comment: looks better now, but now I lost the bottom positioning, see my update

Comment: can you set a working fiddle or snippet  so    i can show you where to add the rule : `flex:1` for description, else read again any tutorials about flex and justify-content :)

Comment: thank you @GCyrillus I used `flex: 1`in the description and is working now, but not 100% good tho. As soon as I get the fix I'll update it here. I'll give it one more shot.